# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable beatifulsoup category and subcategory href pr

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

I am trying to scrap a website, I could get product details but i got an error while trying to get all categories and sub categories links to visit all pages.  The error is saying the link is string but when i open link on web manually i can reach the website. I added the error below

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
from unidecode import unidecode
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

URL = 'https://www.tapwarehouse.com/'

def get_category_links(URL):
    category_links = []
    browser.get(URL)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
    cat=soup.find_all("ul",{"class":"c-nav__list"})[0].find_all('a')
    for i in cat:
        try:
            link=i["href"]
            if link=='javascript:void(0)':
                pass
            else:
                category_links.append("https://www.tapwarehouse.com"+i["href"])
        except:
            pass
    return category_links

def get_sub_category_links(URL):
    sub_category_links=[]
    browser.get(URL)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': "m-categories__menu__link"}):
        sub_category_links.append("https://www.tapwarehouse.com/"+link["href"])
    return sub_category_links

response = []
sublist=[]
urllist=[]
for cat_link in get_category_links(URL = URL):
    for subcat_obj in get_sub_category_links(URL = cat_link):
        try:
            get_sub_category_links = subcat_obj
            print(f'sub category is {get_sub_category_links}')
            sublist.append(get_sub_category_links)
            sublist = list(set(sublist))
        except:
            pass

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-8873cbd974a9> in <module>
      4 for cat_link in get_category_links(URL = URL):
----> 5     for subcat_obj in get_sub_category_links(URL = cat_link):

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: `get_sub_category_links` (while it refers to a function) returns a list of strings, `for subcat_obj in get_sub_category_links(...)` assigns one of the strings to `subcat_obj` and `get_sub_category_links = subcat_obj` assigns this string to `get_sub_category_links`.

Comment: but it should be href while i tried manually i can open link

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the variable `get_sub_category_links` two times: one as a function, one as a variable (in the try/except): `get_sub_category_links = subcat_obj`

You should use a different name to define the variable in the loop, maybe you can rename it to just `sub_category_link`. So replace the code in the "try/except" by:

```
sub_category_link = subcat_obj
print(f'sub category is {sub_category_link}')
sublist.append(sub_category_link)
sublist = list(set(sublist))
```

Comment: I got your point and i tried it but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Selenium is not the right tool for the job here: you're trying to get those category links: why not do something like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import json
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()
r = s.get('https://www.tapwarehouse.com/')
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
menu_items = soup.select('ul[class="c-nav__list"] li[class="c-nav__item c-nav__item--10"]')
for item in menu_items:
    try:
        top_link = item.select_one('a[data-test="nav-top-level-link"]')
        sublinks_obj = json.loads(item.select_one('script[class="js-sub-nav-data"]').string)
        df = pd.json_normalize(sublinks_obj, record_path=['Items', 'Items', 'Items'])
        df['Category'] = item.select_one('a[data-test="nav-top-level-link"]').get_text(strip=True)
        big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
big_df['Url'] = big_df.apply(lambda row: 'https://www.tapwarehouse.com' + row.Url, axis=1)
display(big_df[['Category', 'Title', 'Url']])

# big_df[['Category', 'Title', 'Url']].to_csv('kitchen_stuffs.csv', index=False) ## in case you want to save it as a .csv file
```

The output looks like:

```
Category    Title   Url
0   Kitchen Taps    Modern  https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/kitchen-taps/kitchen-taps-modern
1   Kitchen Taps    Traditional https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/kitchen-taps/kitchen-taps-traditional
2   Kitchen Taps    Pull Out    https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/kitchen-taps/kitchen-taps-pull-out-spray
3   Kitchen Taps    Boiling Water   https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/kitchen-taps/boiling-water-taps
4   Kitchen Taps    Filtered Water  https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/kitchen-taps/kitchen-taps-water-filter-taps
... ... ... ...
281 Brands  Thomas Denby    https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/brands/thomas-denby
282 Brands  Uniblade    https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/brands/other-brands/uniblade
283 Brands  Vado    https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/brands/other-brands/vado
284 Brands  Vellamo https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/brands/vellamo
285 Brands  Villeroy & Boch https://www.tapwarehouse.com/c/brands/other-brands/villeroy-boch-kitchen-sinks
286 rows × 3 columns
```

You can inspect that JSON data and play around with it, maybe extract other stuffs from it. See relevant Pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), as well as [Requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I just missed '/' after website href